# Positive and negative voltage readings across a rig simulating bearing contact, supplied with a DC source

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, dc, remote-control, negative-voltage

I recently ran a few experiments to simulate the effects of shaft voltages on motor bearings through using a simplified experimental rig. The rig simulates bearing contact. I applied a DC source across the rig using carbon slip rings and connected a resistor in series to limit the maximum current.

The data from the experiment is quite interesting.

A schematic of the simplified circuit is shows as:

[image]

The voltage supply was set to 10 V.

The elastohydroydnamic film is said to behave as a capacitor, assuming the discs are completely serrated by a lubricating film.

The data recorded:

[image]

and

[image]

The first graph (blue) recorded RV (resistor potential difference) and the second graph (red) recorded the voltage across the bearing contact.

What's very strange to me is the fluctuation in voltage above and below 0. An analytical solution would suggest that the voltage across the rig should not be negative, due to captive or ohmic behaviour.

Any possible reasons for the negative potential difference?

Answer (score 0):

One might reasonably assume that the capacitance provided by the film will vary as the motor rotates.  If the capacitance reduces (larger gap or smaller surface area) and the charge stays the same then the voltage across the capacitor must increase since Q=1/2CV^2.  That’s the principle of operation of the Wimshurst machine.  The situation is somewhat more complicated because the capacitor is in a circuit rather than acting as a standalone device.  It does seem strange that the voltage drop is mostly across the resistor rather than the capacitor though, I would expect the capacitor to charge to 10V and then no DC current flow, unless the film breaks down momentarily and discharges the capacitance.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would assume the film breaks down momentarily and discharges once the potential exceeds the dielectric strength of the lubricant. Also the peaks in voltage observed could be the breakdown voltage of the lubricant, a zoom in of the data shows spikes in voltage in the positive and negative direction to roughly the same potential, showing some sort of symmetry in signal. I am still unsure on the cause of an alternating direction of voltage, could the discharge be occurring from both directions between the cathode and anode?